# Why does the graph of the electric potential of a conducting sphere look like this?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, voltage, gauss-law, conductors

[image: electric potential inside a conducting sphere]

The graph of the electric potential of a conducting sphere with radius $R$ is curved when $r > R.$ Since the electric potential outside the sphere is $k\frac{Q}{r},$ shouldn't the graph be linear instead of being curved? The electric field, which is $k\frac{Q}{r^2},$ also decreases in that fashion, so I'm confused...how can different equations seem to have similar graphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curves for $kQ/r^2$  and $kQ/r$ might look similar but there is difference in their curvature and geometry.

$kQ/r^2$ and $kQ/r$ might look deceivingly similar but they are 2 different curves.